# How to set the calendar to mm-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to set the calendar as showing only month and year. As I am using [React-Date-Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker#react-date-picker) npm package. I tried it by using below code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';
 
function MyApp() {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());
 
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        formatDate="MMMM YYYY"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In abobe code I also tried with this [link](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar#props) and use **formatMonth** as given in [user guide](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar#user-guide) table.
but It's not working for me.

How can we solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done natively using the `Date` class.

```js
function format(date) {
  return [(date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'), date.getFullYear()].join('-')
}

console.log(format(new Date()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) for formatting the date. And update your code as follow:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

...

<DatePicker
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
    formatLongDate={(locale, date) => dayjs(date).format('MM-YYYY')}
/>

...
```